# pre-selected values for a dynamic drop-down box

Tags: php

Here is my problem, I have dropdown which used to save the selected option to a SQL database. Now I have an Edit option where the same dropdown is created dynamically to give the user to select and alternate option and save the edit. When the edit page launches I want the dropdown to be pre-selected the value already saved in the database.

I use following code to get done the similar thing with a textbox but strugling to put the same value attribute to the dropdown.

```
 <input name='routename' type='text'  value='".htmlentities($row['route'])."'> // This is working for the textbox
```

can someone tell me how to do this with a dropdown box? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little more complicated but can be achieved with this:

```
<select name="something">
    <option value="1"<?=($row['something'] == 1)? ' selected="selected"':''?>>Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"<?=($row['something'] == 2)? ' selected="selected"':''?>>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you see an error in this code? Thanks echo "<option value='Daily'".($row['freq'] == 'Daily')."'? ' selected='selected' ':''">Daily</option>"

Comment: Yes, this is what it should look like: `echo "<option value='Daily'".(($row['freq'] == 'Daily') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Daily</option>";`. Try to keep consistency in using single and double quotes, it can get confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use conditional code as you generate your `<option>` nodes like this:

```
<?php
echo '<option ';
if ($value == $selected_value)
    echo 'selected="selected"';
echo 'value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs)){

if($row['id']==$value){
   $selected='selected';
}else{
    $selected='';
}

echo '<option value="$row['id']" $selected >$row['value']</option>';
}
```